# How do you make Snake roll?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I'm trying to get Snake to roll so I can collect the XOF patch that's on him but I can't. Does he only roll those couple of times until the patch falls off? I'm pressing L1 + L3 but nothing is happening. This is on PS3 by the way. I can't remember if I've gotten this patch before .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out. After messing around with the controls for a bit I realized that you hold down L1 while laying down, move to the left or right and click on L3.